# dialogflow app fail to start on locked phone?

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have created a test agent in dialog flow and it works well on my Samsung S8 when it's unlocked with headphones.
When the phone is locked and I try to start the app with headphones, I get the answer "not supported on this device" by Google Assistant.
The same thing happens if I try to test the application on Andriod auto.
Is there any setting that can be set to make the app work when the phone is locked?
Info: using Swedish language on the phone.

Comment: do you have Bixby on your phone?

Comment: Yes, it's installed on the phone.

Comment: set google as a default assistant

Comment: Google Assistant works on the phone, it just does not start my Dialog flow agent when I want to test it when the phone is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Check Google Settings on your phone. There is an option that enables OK Google detection on locked and headphones.

Comment: The options for headphones and bluetooth on locked device is enabled.
Do you know if it's possible to run DialogFlow agents on locked device or Android Auto?

Comment: Have you created Android assistant?

Comment: Yes, if you mean Google Assistant is installed and working.

Comment: No I meant if you used Dialogflow and Actions on Google to create the Google Assistant app. Dialogflow can be used to create Chatbot for different other platforms. But only Android assistant may be qualified to trigger from locked screen as we can set OK Google to respond from headphones and licked screen and even unlock the phone with voice.

Comment: Yes, I have used DialogFlow to create a simple app that I will later write a webhook to.
It works and starts with the command "Talk to my test app" after I say "Ok Google" or trigger the microphone on the headset when the phone is unlocked, but it does not start for some reason when the phone is locked. I get answered that the application is not supported by This device from the Assistant.